# Create batches of one single example

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow

after reading tensorflow documentation about [tf.train.batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) .I got these questions in mind :

- is it possible to create batches of one single example?
- And what is the purpose behind that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create batches of a single example. However, the purpose of using batches is for efficiency. Due to overheads, it's possible that running a batch size of 128 may be faster than running 128 batches of 1. As a result, your model may train (or converge) faster by using batches.